# How to get string array from core console appSettings.json file

Tags: c#, appsettings, .net-core-2.0

How do I return an `string[]` from the `IConfigurationRoot` object?

File exists and is set to copy to output

Code

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
_configuration = builder.Build();

var arr = _configuration["stringArray"]; // this returns null
var arr1 = _configuration["stringArray:0"]; // this works and returns first element
```

Settings.json

```
{
  "stringArray": [
    "myString1",
    "myString2",
    "myString3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`GetValue<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_GetValue__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_String_) extension to get the value of the section.

```
// Requires NuGet package "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder"
var array = _configuration.GetValue<string[]>("stringArray");
```

Or try binding to the section

```
var values = new List<string>();
_configuration.Bind("stringArray", values);
```

Alternatively [`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get) syntax can also be used, which results in more compact code:

```
List<string values = _configuration.GetSection("stringArray").Get<string[]>();
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Comment: Thanks! The 2nd method works. Also, just to comment here, it's disheartening to need 3 external nuget packages just to read text from a file, then another one just to get the info from it. Seems like this is way over-complicated.

Comment: The 1st method seems intuitive, but returns `null` for me. The 3rd one works.